# Переделка стандартного цикла for для поддержки параллельной обработки данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, pandas, multiprocessing

Помогите переделать функцию так, чтобы имплементировать многопоточную обработку данных и тем самым повысить скорость вычислений в N раз.

Я думаю что нужно менять ниже приведенный блок. Делить `r_set_list` на диапазоны и делать проверку на выполнение условия, и если хоть в одном диапазоне условие не выполняется, то прекращать проверку (убивая все остальные потоки). Как это красиво и кратко закодить пока не понимаю. И сложность сколько не в закодить и выбрать правильную стратегию распараллеливания. Затраты на организацию параллельной проверки внутри цикла, может потребовать больше ресурсов чем обработки в однопоточном режиме. Ведь код должен убивать все потоки, если хоть в одном из них выполнилось условие. А условие может выполниться на первом же элементе.

```
            f = True 
            for x in r_set_list:
                if (len(x & r_set)) > similar:
                    f = False
                    break
```

Исходный код

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import itertools as itr

df = pd.DataFrame(itr.combinations(range(1,26),6))
similar = 4
#print(df)

def FilterSimilarRecords(df, similar):
        r_set_list = list()
        bool_list = list()
        count = 0


        for r in df.values:
            count += 1
            if(count%100000 == 0):
                print("i:{}, r:{}".format(count, len(r_set_list)))

            r_set = set(r)

            f = True 
            for x in r_set_list:
                if (len(x & r_set)) > similar:
                    f = False
                    break

            if (f):
                bool_list.append(True)
                r_set_list.append(r_set)
            else:
                bool_list.append(False)

        return ~np.array(bool_list)
```

time_start = timer()
result = df[FilterSimilarRecords(df, similar)]
time_delta = timer() - time_start
print('Execution time:', time_delta)
print(result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Я предположил следующие варианты решения:**

1. Оптимизировать однопоточный код.
2. Разбить исполнение на потоки.
3. Использовать JIT-компилятор.
4. Использовать GPU.
5. Использовать "более быстрые" языки программирования.

**О том, что я не попробовал:**

4. Т.к. в конкретной задаче мы создает список уникальных значений и проходы по нему занимают основное время, то использование GPU может сильно ускорить задачу. Надеюсь, специалисты по Tensorflow, numba и пр. смогут написать пример быстрее, чем я разберусь. [О проблематике подобных вычислений на GPU](https://towardsdatascience.com/numpy-vs-tensorflow-speed-on-matrix-calculations-9cbff6b3ce04)
5. На C, Asm и пр. я не писал больше 10 лет и желания вспоминать - нет. ИМХО результат должен быть, как минимум, не сильно хуже варианта №3. Ну и т.к. речь в вопросе о Python, то этот вариант за рамками, я думаю.

**Для тестирования я выделил из кода автора главное:**

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import itertools as itr
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arr = list(itr.combinations(range(1,26),6))
similar = 4

def FilterSimilarRecords(df, similar):
        r_set_list = list()
        bool_list = list()

        for r in df.values:
            r_set = set(r)

            f = True 
            for x in r_set_list:
                if (len(x & r_set)) > similar:
                    f = False
                    break

            if (f):
                bool_list.append(True)
                r_set_list.append(r_set)
            else:
                bool_list.append(False)

        return ~np.array(bool_list)

time_start = timer()
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
result = df[FilterSimilarRecords(df, similar)]
time_delta = timer() - time_start
print('Execution time:', time_delta)
print(result)
```

Результат: `72s [171468 rows x 6 columns]`

**1. Оптимизация однопоточного кода:**

Исходя из [тестов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1009939/253345) отдельных блоков задачи, наиболее быстрым однопоточным вариантом стал:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import itertools as itr
import pandas as pd

arr = list(itr.combinations(range(1,26),6))
similar = 4

def FilterSimilarRecords(records, similar):
    unique = []
    nonunique = []
    # unique = deque()  # Аналогичный результат.
    # nonunique = deque()

    for r in records:
        r = set(r)
        for u in unique:
            if (len(u & r)) > similar:
                nonunique.append(r)
                break
        else:
            unique.append(r)
    return nonunique

time_start = timer()
filtered = pd.DataFrame(FilterSimilarRecords(arr, similar))
time_delta = timer() - time_start
print('Execution time:', time_delta)
print(filtered)
```

Результат: `65s [171468 rows x 6 columns]`

**2. Разбить исполнение на потоки:**

Многопоточность - не помогает. Специфика задачи такова, что процессор остается не нагружен, а узким местом является доступ к памяти. Соответственно, мы наблюдаем снижение производительности из-за накладных расходов на организацию многопоточности.

Исходя из [тестов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1009996/253345) отдельных блоков задачи, наиболее быстрым многопоточным вариантом стал:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import itertools as itr
import pandas as pd

arr = list(itr.combinations(range(1,26),6))

class FilterSimilarRecords:
    pool = Pool(16)
    unique = []
    nonunique = []
    similar = 4
    is_unique = True

    def run(self, arr):
        for a in arr:
            self.is_unique = True
            self.record = set(a)
            self.pool.map(self.apply, self.unique)
            if self.is_unique:
                self.unique.append(self.record)
            else:
                self.nonunique.append(self.record)

        return self.nonunique

    def apply(self, u):
        if (len(u & self.record)) > self.similar:
            self.is_unique = False
            raise StopIteration


time_start = timer()
result = FilterSimilarRecords().run(arr)
filtered = pd.DataFrame(result)
time_delta = timer() - time_start
print('Execution time:', time_delta)
print(filtered)
```

Результат: `392s [171468 rows x 6 columns]` C try, except - результат аналогичен.

**3. Использовать JIT-компилятор:**

Наиболее быстрый из протестированних на CPU. `np.array` - медленнее. Буду рад, если кто-нибудь реализует на GPU. У меня "с наскока" ничего хорошего не вышло.

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import itertools as itr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import numba

arr = np.array(list(itr.combinations(range(1,26),6)))
similar = 4

@numba.njit(target='cpu')
def FilterSimilarRecords(arr, similar):
    unique = list()
    nonunique = list()
    for a in range(arr.shape[0]):
        r = set(arr[a])
        for u in range(len(unique)):
            if (len(unique[u] & r)) > similar:
                nonunique.append(arr[a])
                break
        else:
            unique.append(r)
    return nonunique

time_start = timer()
filtered = pd.DataFrame(FilterSimilarRecords(arr, similar))
time_delta = timer() - time_start
print('Execution time:', time_delta)
print(filtered)
```

Результат: `50s [171468 rows x 6 columns]`

Comment: Интересно решение на GPU. Есть идея оптимизировать алгоритм для 1) и 3) случаев.  Суммировать элементы строки и делать поиск по диапазону сумм. На днях выложу код.

Comment: Меня интересовала оптимизация для "общего случая". Т.е. с возможностью использования в иных расчетах.

Comment: Для "общего случая" сложновато будет. В вашем случае в строке могут быть не уникальные значения? В моем только уникальные. В задаче самая тяжелая часть выпадает на (len(u & r)) > similar .  Я думал переводить u и r в int128  (в моей задаче макс знач. элемента = 80). В теории побитовая операция & быстрая, но вот подсчет кол-во бит будет медленным. Поэтому оставил эту затею.

Comment: Под "общим случаем", я понимал применение быстрой функции к длинному списку.

Comment: Кстати for a in range(arr.shape[0]) нельзя параллелить, поскольку тогда может нарушиться логика выборки. Данные должны сканироваться и обрабатываться последовательно. А вы можете показать GPU версию пусть даже медленную?

Comment: Кстати плиз к чему относяться строки         else: unique.append(r). По синтаксису не к блоку if. Понять не могу как это работает.

Comment: Где у меня `for a in range(arr.shape[0])` параллелится? JIT-компилятор работает в один поток. GPU-версию уже не могу, т.к. удалил ноутбук. Советую попробовать сделать самостоятельно, а если не получится, задать отдельный вопрос, касающийся возникшей проблемы.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97067/discussion-between-anton-abrosimov-and-yuriy-tigiev).

Comment: @YuriyTigiev Можно еще в эту сторону посмотреть: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1010547/253345

Comment: Смотрел. Не совсем подходит для решение текущей задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Улучшенная однопоточная версию - 1. Оптимизация однопоточного кода

Тесты делались на ноутбуке. CPU i5-6200 2.30GHZ

Исходная версия: `Execution time: 184.5349679`

Улучшенная версия: `Execution time: 107.32932070000004`

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import itertools as itr
import pandas as pd
import gmpy2

def ListIntToBigInt(lst):
    return sum(2**i for i in lst)

df = pd.DataFrame(list(itr.combinations(range(1,26),6)))

similar = 4

def FilterSimilarRecords(df, similar):
    dct = df.T.to_dict('list')
    dct_bin = dict(map(lambda item: (item[0], ListIntToBigInt(item[1])), dct.items()))

    unique = []
    unique_key = []
    key = 0

    len_dct = len(dct)

    while key < len_dct:
        r = dct_bin[key]
        for u in unique:
            if (gmpy2.popcount(u & r)) > similar:
                break
        else:
            unique.append(r)
            unique_key.append(key)

        key += 1

    return df[~df.index.isin(unique_key)]

time_start = timer()
filtered = FilterSimilarRecords(df, similar)
time_delta = timer() - time_start
print('Execution time:', time_delta)
print(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

Улучшенная многопоточная версию - 2. Разбить исполнение на потоки

Тесты делались на ноутбуке. CPU i5-6200 2.30GHZ

Исходная версия: `Execution time: 559.0649321000001`

Улучшенная версия: `Execution time: 268.8355488999996`

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import itertools as itr
import pandas as pd
import gmpy2

df = pd.DataFrame(list(itr.combinations(range(1,26),6)))


class FilterSimilarRecords:
    pool = Pool(16)
    unique = []
    unique_key = []    
    is_unique = True

    def run(self, df, similar):
        dct = df.T.to_dict('list')
        dct_bin = dict(map(lambda item: (item[0], self.ListIntToBigInt(item[1])), dct.items()))

        lst_x = 0
        lst_y = 0
        lst = []
        lst_size = 10000
        len_dct = len(dct) 
        unique = []
        unique_key = []        
        key = 0
        self.similar = similar

        while key < len_dct:
            self.record = dct_bin[key]
            self.is_unique = True
            self.pool.map(self.apply_lst, lst)
            if self.is_unique:
                self.unique.append(self.record)
                self.unique_key.append(key)

                if(lst_x > lst_size):
                    lst_x = 0
                    lst_y += 1
                    lst.append([])
                elif (lst_x == 0):
                    lst.append([])

                l = lst[lst_y]
                l.append(self.record)
                lst_x += 1                

            key += 1

        return df[~df.index.isin(self.unique_key)]

    def apply_lst(self, u):
        if(next(filter(lambda x: (gmpy2.popcount(self.record & x)) > self.similar, u)) != None):
            self.is_unique = False
            raise StopIteration            


    def ListIntToBigInt(self, lst):
        return sum(2**i for i in lst)


time_start = timer()
result = FilterSimilarRecords().run(df, 4)
time_delta = timer() - time_start
print('Execution time:', time_delta)
print(result)
```