# Быстрый способ применить простую функцию к длинному списку

Tags: python, python-3.x, оптимизация, список

Есть простая и быстрая функция, например: `set()`, и длинный список, например: `list(itr.combinations(range(1, 30), 6))`.
Не принимая в расчет время, потраченное на конвертирование исходных данных в другой тип объекта, в случае необходимости.
Какой самый быстрый способ применить функцию к каждой строке списка?

Вопрос является частью ответа на: [Переделка стандартного цикла for для поддержки параллельной обработки данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1005910/253345)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следующий код позволит измерить скорость применения функции к `list`, `np.array`, `pd.DataFrame`, `deque`.

```
import itertools as itr
from collections import deque
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# Без вызова сборщика мусора,
# результат зависит от очередности вызовов.
import gc

lst = list(itr.combinations(range(1, 20), 6))
arr = np.array(lst)
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
dq = deque(lst)

print('df for:')
gc.collect()
%timeit [set(i) for _, i in df.iterrows()]
gc.collect()
print('df apply:')
%timeit df.apply(set, axis=1)
gc.collect()
print('arr apply:')
%timeit np.apply_along_axis(set, axis=1, arr=arr)
gc.collect()
print('arr for:')
%timeit [set(i) for i in arr]
gc.collect()
print('lst multithread map:')
pool = Pool(16) # Кол-во потоков CPU.
%timeit pool.map(set, lst)
gc.collect()
print('batched lst multithread map:')
b = 10240
blst = [lst[i:i+b] for i in range(0, len(lst), b)]
pool = Pool(16)
%timeit pool.map(lambda x: [set(i) for i in x], blst)
gc.collect()
print('lst map:')
%timeit list(map(set, lst))
gc.collect()
print('deque for:')
%timeit [set(i) for i in dq]
gc.collect()
print('lst for:')
%timeit [set(i) for i in lst]
gc.collect()
```

Результат теста на моей системе:

```
df for:
1.55 s ± 20.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
df apply:
358 ms ± 8.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
arr apply:
113 ms ± 1.87 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
arr for:
52.4 ms ± 486 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
lst multithread map:
23.7 ms ± 716 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
batched lst multithread map:
23.5 ms ± 1.15 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
lst map:
16.4 ms ± 215 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
deque for:
16.5 ms ± 324 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
lst for:
16.3 ms ± 464 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Мои победители с средним результатом `16.4`:

- `[set(i) for i in lst]`
- `list(map(set, lst))`
- `[set(i) for i in dq]`