# Как подружить модуль gmpy2 с multiprocess?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Как подружить модуль gmpy2 с  multiprocess без потери производительности?
При выполнении `p.map(lambda x: (gmpy2.popcount(x & y) ),  с)` получаю сообщение об ошибке `name 'gmpy2' is not defined`
В случае если `p.map` заменить на `map` - все работает корректно.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import gmpy2
from multiprocess import Pool
import itertools as itr

def ListIntToBigInt(lst):
    return sum(2**i for i in lst)

p = Pool(4)
с = p.map(ListIntToBigInt, list(itr.combinations(range(1,16),6)))

y = ListIntToBigInt([2,3,4,7,10])
similar = 4 

m = list(p.map(lambda x: (gmpy2.popcount(x & y) ),  с))
m
```

Comment: Может `multiprocessing`, а не `multiprocess`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А многопоточность вам не подойдет?

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
```

Если процессор (физический) один, то: `multiprocessing.dummy` будет быстрее, т.к. создание потока "дешевле" создания процесса.

Если процессоров несколько, то многопоточность не будет работать одновременно на нескольких процессорах.

Comment: Все что угодно лишь бы повысить скорость обработки на компьютере.

Comment: Работает. Ошибок не дает, но скрипт начал в 4 раза медленее работать.

Comment: @AnotnAbrosimov - p.map работает в 4 раза медленее чем map, при p = Pool(4)

Comment: @YuriyTigiev Вероятно, ваша проблема описана в этом моем вопросе/ответе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1009996/253345 Еще этот мой тест, возможно, вам поможет: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1009939/253345

Comment: @YuriyTigiev На тему математики, еще может помочь этот пост: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1010547/253345