# Как быстрее применить быструю функцию к длинному списку? В один поток, или в несколько?

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, список

Есть простая и быстрая функция, например: `set()`, и длинный список, например: `list(itr.combinations(range(1, 30), 6))`.

Как быстрее применить функцию к каждой строке списка, в один или несколько потоков?

Вопрос является частью ответа на: [Переделка стандартного цикла for для поддержки параллельной обработки данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1005910/253345)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Тест однопоточной обработки и многопоточного `map`.

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import itertools as itr
import gc

data = list(itr.combinations(range(1, 30), 6))

def classic_map():
    return list(map(set, data))

def multithread_map():
    pool = Pool(16)  # Кол-во потоков == кол-ву потоков CPU.
    return pool.map(set, data)

for ex in (classic_map, multithread_map):
    time_start = timer()
    ex()
    time_delta = timer() - time_start
    print(ex.__name__, time_delta)
    del ex
    gc.collect()
```

### Результат:

```
classic_map 0.7905314989574254
multithread_map 0.8719341289252043
```

## Тест модуля threading:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import itertools as itr
import threading
from queue import Queue
import gc


class Thread_ManyBatch(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name, queue, result):
        super().__init__()
        self.queue = queue
        self.name = name
        self.result = result
        self.stop = False

    def run(self):
        while not self.stop:
            item = self.queue.get()
            for i in item:
                self.result.append(set(i))
            self.queue.task_done()


class Calculate:
    def __init__(self, threads):
        self.result = []
        self.queue = Queue()
        self.threads = []
        for i in range(threads):
            t = Thread_ManyBatch(f'№{i}',
                self.queue, self.result)
            t.setDaemon(True)
            t.start()
            self.threads.append(t)

    def __call__(self, input_array):
        for i in input_array:
            self.queue.put(i)
        self.queue.join()
        return self

    def __del__(self):
        for t in self.threads:
            t.stop = True
        for _ in self.threads:
            self.queue.put([])


def run_test(t, b):
    calc = Calculate(t)
    data = [arr[i:i+b] for i in range(0, len(arr), b)]
    time_start = timer()
    result = calc(data).result
    time_delta = timer() - time_start
    print(f'(Thread) Потоков: {t} Блок: {b} Время: {time_delta}')
    del data, result, calc


# Мой CPU имеет 16 потоков.
arr = list(itr.combinations(range(1, 30), 6))
conditions = [
    {'threads': 4, 'batch': 64},
    {'threads': 8, 'batch': 64},
    {'threads': 16, 'batch': 64},
    {'threads': 32, 'batch': 64},
    {'threads': 64, 'batch': 64},

    {'threads': 16, 'batch': 16},
    {'threads': 16, 'batch': 32},
    {'threads': 16, 'batch': 64},
    {'threads': 16, 'batch': 128},

    {'threads': 16, 'batch': len(arr)},

    {'threads': 16, 'batch': len(arr)//4},
    {'threads': 16, 'batch': len(arr)//8},
    {'threads': 16, 'batch': len(arr)//16},
    {'threads': 16, 'batch': len(arr)//32},
    {'threads': 16, 'batch': len(arr)//64},
    {'threads': 16, 'batch': len(arr)//128},
    {'threads': 16, 'batch': len(arr)//256},
    {'threads': 16, 'batch': len(arr)//512},
    {'threads': 32, 'batch': len(arr)//512},
]
for cond in conditions:
    t = cond['threads']
    b = cond['batch']
    gc.collect()
    run_test(t, b)
```

### Результат:

```
(Thread) Потоков: 4 Блок: 64 Время: 1.3617786209797487
(Thread) Потоков: 8 Блок: 64 Время: 1.3240357339382172
(Thread) Потоков: 16 Блок: 64 Время: 1.2864610340911895
(Thread) Потоков: 32 Блок: 64 Время: 1.2982085599796847
(Thread) Потоков: 64 Блок: 64 Время: 1.3388550870586187
# Обратите внимание ^ Лучшее кол-во потоков = кол-ву потоков моего CPU (16).
(Thread) Потоков: 16 Блок: 16 Время: 2.04451086896006
(Thread) Потоков: 16 Блок: 32 Время: 1.6462758219568059
(Thread) Потоков: 16 Блок: 64 Время: 1.3170949750347063
(Thread) Потоков: 16 Блок: 128 Время: 1.2290826480602846
# Обратите внимание ^ Увеличение размера блока улучшает время.
(Thread) Потоков: 16 Блок: 475020 Время: 0.8684073160402477
# Обратите внимание ^ Размер блока = кол-ву элементов списка.
# По сути мы реализовали работу в один поток.
(Thread) Потоков: 16 Блок: 118755 Время: 1.0302920539397746
(Thread) Потоков: 16 Блок: 59377 Время: 1.0756338470382616
(Thread) Потоков: 16 Блок: 29688 Время: 1.0272350820014253
(Thread) Потоков: 16 Блок: 14844 Время: 0.9970859980676323
(Thread) Потоков: 16 Блок: 7422 Время: 1.0095931380055845
(Thread) Потоков: 16 Блок: 3711 Время: 0.9970878609456122
(Thread) Потоков: 16 Блок: 1855 Время: 1.02392076398246
(Thread) Потоков: 16 Блок: 927 Время: 1.1156460139900446
(Thread) Потоков: 32 Блок: 927 Время: 1.0031342359725386
# Обратите внимание ^ Уменьшение размера блока нам ничего не дает.
```

### Итог:

- Самый быстрый способ: классический однопоточный перебор `list`.
- Кол-во потоков должно равняться кол-ву потоков CPU.
- Деление на блоки ухудшает время.
- `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` практически аналогичен `threading`.

### Почему так?

Все дело в том, что узким местом тут является доступ к памяти. Процессорного времени, необходимого для выполнения `set()`, требуется слишком мало, чтобы полностью загрузить даже один поток моего процессора. В результате, хоть в один поток, хоть в 16 потоков, мой процессор простаивает ожидая очередной элемент списка из памяти.

### Зачем тогда многопоточность?

- Для вычислений. Данных может быть не много, но "математических" операций над каждым элементом надо сделать много.
- Когда узкое место "ждет". Например получение данных из сети. Пока один поток ждет во время установки соединения, другой уже качает. Более того, пока один поток качает, другой уже обрабатывает полученные данные. Или пока один поток ждет пользователя, другой вычисляет в фоне. Но это все уже к асинхронности.

### Почему у вас могут быть другие результаты этих тестов?

Слабый процессор, быстрый доступ к памяти. Узким местом на вашей системе оказался процессор, а не доступ к памяти. Еще стоит обратить внимание на фоновую нагрузку. Ведь этот тест не единственная работающая программа на вашей системе. Еще обратите внимание на то, что если фоновая нагрузка высокая, то большее кол-во потоков будет чаще получать управление от планировщика системы.

Comment: Ядро тратит много времени на Read или Write? Ведь чтение не блокирует участок памяти.  Если list разделить на несколько независимых списков, то cache каждого ядра поможет решить проблему с медленной памятью?

Comment: Судя по тесту `threading` - не помогает. Вам будет проще реализовать это на Си. И использовать функцию Си в Питоне.

Comment: Я хочу выжать максимум из python и библиотек, чтобы лучше понимать возможности языка. Я кодил brute force  на c и c# и там проще какие-то вещи организовать. Меня еще интересует как data sciencist решают задачи с большим объемом данных в контексте производительности вычислений. Ведь моя задача не самая сложная и уверен, что эксперт найдет красивое и простое решение.