# Как реализовать многопоточность в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет!Не могу разобраться с многопоточностью в Python.

У меня есть 2 скрипта. Один - главный, второй - содержит функцию, которую я хочу запустить параллельно главному процессу.

Main Script:

```
import threading
#мой подключаемый скрипт
import train_liveness as train

t = Thread(target=train.train)

while True:
  read += 1

  ........


  if (read == 25):
    t.start()
```

Function train из train_liveness

```
def train()
  .......
  return True
```

Пока что получилось сделать только заморозку главного процесса до момента завершения второго потока с помощью .join().

Но моя задача немного другая - запустить именно параллельно, чтобы функция выполнялась независимо от главного скрипта.

Еще проблема, я хочу получить свое значение из функции, которое она вернет - True. Это поможет мне понять, что функция завершилась и я могу закрыть поток.

И да, не нашла функцию для закрытия потока. После отработки функции поток не убивается и в следующий раз, когда я пытаюсь запустить t.start(), он, естественно, ругается, что поток уже запущен.

Подскажите, как я могу решить эту проблему? Если не сложно, приведите пример кода, а не ссылки на документацию. Спасибо!

Comment: Потоки не подлежат переиспользованию, второй раз `start` вызывать нельзя, нужно создать новый поток.

Comment: Что должен делать ваш главный скрипт, пока функция выполняется в другом потоке?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev главный скрипт считывает информацию с веб-камеры и выводит ее на экран.

Comment: В таком случае просто не вызывайте `join`. Данные из потока передавайте через [очередь](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html). В главном скрипте периодически вызывайте `get_nowait` для получения данных из потока. Или используйте [Executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor) и назначьте функцию обратного вызова на `future`.

Comment: Ваш пример, так сказать, не показательный. Мне кажется, что вы пытаетесь реализовать "асинхронность", с помощью "многопоточности". https://webdevblog.ru/obzor-async-io-v-python-3-7/ Тут есть пара примеров того, как реализуется "многопоточность": https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1009997/253345

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример
import threading
import time

```py
def Thread(my_funk): # Будет выступать в роли декоратора
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        my_thread = threading.Thread(target=my_funk, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        my_thread.start()

    return wrapper

@Thread
def f1():
    time.sleep(1)
    print('f1 - finished')

@Thread
def f2():
    time.sleep(2)
    print('f2 - finished')

@Thread
def f3():
    print('f3 - finished')

print('all func started')

f1()
f2()
f3()
#вывод
#all func started
#f3 - finished
#f1 - finished
#f2 - finished
```

Если бы не было декоратора, то поток программы выполнялся бы с функции f1 и **ждал** окончание ее работы, потом переходил к дальнейшим функциям